# Ubuntu 16.04 server kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill error

Tags: server, kernel

After upgrading my server's RAM from *16 to 64*, I have get the following error on system loading. [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNdC7.jpg)

```
kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000200
```

The server's os is *ubuntu 16.04* server on *vmware*. Please kindly let me know how to fix the problem.

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNdC7.jpg)

Comment: Does the error go away if you reduce the servers RAM agian to 16?

Comment: No, unfortunately it seems it not related to RAM upgrading